# 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 in react native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

when I am trying to run my react native app on the ios simulator I am getting this error.

Error:

```
duplicate symbol '_EXCanAskAgain' in:
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXPermissions/libEXPermissions.a(EXPermissions.o)
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_EXExpiresKey' in:
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXPermissions/libEXPermissions.a(EXPermissions.o)
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_EXGrantedKey' in:
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXPermissions/libEXPermissions.a(EXPermissions.o)
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_EXPermissionExpiresNever' in:
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXPermissions/libEXPermissions.a(EXPermissions.o)
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_EXStatusKey' in:
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXPermissions/libEXPermissions.a(EXPermissions.o)
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXPermissionsService.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy' in:
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXPermissions/libEXPermissions.a(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy' in:
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXPermissions/libEXPermissions.a(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)
    /Users/harshmishra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myways-gkjarpvjrufpitdstvqcnasxhmrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)
ld: 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried cleaning the build folder, running pod install again but nothing works out. I am stuck on this error. I am not able to find what's causing this error. Also, I have checked myApp > Libraries folder there is nothing(empty folder).

Comment: Try Changing root folder name or location

Comment: Tried this. But it doesn't work.

Comment: are you using multiple scheme?

Comment: @Xhirazi No, I am not using it. But How can I check it again?

Comment: You can check by Product>Scheme>Choose Scheme

Comment: @Xhirazi No, there is no multiple scheme

Answer (score 11):

I had exactly the same error after adding react-native-unimodules library to the app I am working on.

After several hours of trying different solutions we were able to fix the error by downgrading the react-native-unimodules library from the current 0.14.7 version to 0.13.3.

- changed the react-native-unimodules version in package.json
- reinstalled the packages (yarn install for me)
- cd ios, then pod deintegrate (just to be sure), then pod install
- in XCode went to Product tab and Clean Build Folder from there
- launched the app and it compiled successfully

Hope it helps anyone else who encounters the issue.

Comment: Yeah, it worked, but there should be some better way than downgrading lib, tho?

Comment: I can confirm that Robert Loh's solution worked - the build error was gone after upgrading react-native-unimodules to the current version and also adding expo-permissions

Comment: is it still working for you ? @DmitryPetrov

Comment: yes it does - I added expo-permissions and bumped react-native-unimodules to 0.14.7, works fine for me. what issue do you have?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69705826/react-native-0-66-1-unable-to-build-neither-android-nor-ios-bundle this is what i have for now

Comment: I'm using the managed workflow, don't have unimodules or expo-permissions directly installed, and have a similar error.

Comment: Thanks, @DmitryPetrov it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

**SOLVED** **@Jan 20 2022**

**react-native-unimodules** is the main culprit.
since expo has updated itself and react-native-unimodules are now deprecated.

```
yarn remove react-native-unimodules
```

OR

```
npm uninstall react-native-unimodules
```

In pod file

```
# require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'
# use_unimodules!
```

also clean your AppDelegate.m and AppDelegate.h

delete node_modules

```
    pod install
```

make build and good to go.
expo-packages won't work. now delete expo packages that you are currently using from your package.json again yarn install then in iOS directory pod install and make build all good. still expo packages are not working, now search whatever expo-package you want to use and then follow the documentation. Thanks me later.

Comment: How to clean this AppDelegate.m and AppDelegate.h?

Comment: do run above written commands, and then run project, Xcode will through errors, just comment all the lines having error.

Comment: I can't comment some codes because it affected other codes. can you help me please to check this repo https://github.com/potamir/issues-unimodules-ios/tree/main. I put both AppDelegate.m and AppDelegate.h, and also main.m inside it. Thank You!!

Comment: oh nvm, I just comment most of them and it just magically worked. Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome (Y)

Comment: I have another question please,
now it produce this error after complete building metro bundler "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'NativeUnimoduleProxy.viewManagersNames')"

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HzOMTI8

Comment: you aren't using uni modules anymore, check your image remove unicodes?.something, though m not sure but a rough guess.

Answer (score 4):

The expo-permissions in the react-native-unimodules library 0.14.7 is outdated which caused the 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 in react native issue when you build the app. To fix this issue, you need to

- run **npm install expo-permissions**
- run **pod install** in **ios** folder
- build and run iOS app again

Comment: PS: you dont have to downgrade react-native-unimodules, you just need to install the expo-permissions and run pod install to link it.

Comment: is it still working for you? @robert-loh

Comment: Funnily enough, I got 12 duplicate symbols instead of 7 after following your instructions. What version of expo-permissions did you install?

Comment: @Olek yes, mine still working, no issue so far.

Comment: @jperl this is all my expo related dependencies version:
> "expo": "42.0.3",
> "expo-asset": "8.3.3",
> "expo-av": "9.2.3",
> "expo-barcode-scanner": "10.2.2",
> "expo-camera": "11.2.2",
> "expo-font": "9.2.1",
> "expo-linear-gradient": "9.2.0",
> "expo-splash-screen": "0.11.4",
> "expo-status-bar": "1.0.4",
> "expo-updates": "0.8.5",
> "expo-video-thumbnails": "5.2.0",

Comment: I just removed expo-permissions recently due to deprecated issue.

Comment: FYI, my react-native-unimodules version currently is 0.14.8

Answer (score -1):

Try to upgrade `expo-permissions` to latest version